# Show equality of a given function with a series in $ℝ$

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Show that: $$2x\cos x-\sin x=4\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-1}\sin(nx)$$

Supposedly, this can be proved by using Fourier series, by choosing the right function but I have been thus far unable to do so. Any hints will be welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried calculating the fourier coefficients of the left-hand-side ? that should give you the solution.

Comment: @supinf You mean by treating all the left side as a function and calculating its Fourier series?

Comment: yes, that is what i mean.

Comment: Actually I tried calculating $sin(nx)cos(nx)$ with little luck..But if that's the right one,I ll give it a shot.

Comment: Hint: calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-1}e^{inx}$ by using $\ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}x^n$ and then separate the real part from the imaginary part.

Comment: Thanks xpaul-will try to do it.Though I am not very familiar with complex analysis.

Comment: @JDrinas if i am not mistaken, there is no need to calculate $\sin(nx) \cos(nx)$ during the fourier analysis stuff.

Comment: @supinf I don't think you are mistaken! I was just following a hunch but got nowhere..

Comment: Is the series presented correct?

Comment: @Leucippus Yes,unless my professor made a mistake,that's the series :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Fourier sine series 
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_{n} \, \sin(nx)  \hspace{15mm} x \in [0,\pi] \\
B_{n} &= \frac{2}{\pi} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) \, \sin(nx) \, dx
\end{align}
the function $f(x) = a x \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$ can be seen to be represented by
\begin{align}
a x \cos(x) + b \sin(x) = \frac{2b - a}{2} + 2a \, \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, n}{n^{2} -1} \, \sin(nx).
\end{align}
This is obtained by making use of 
\begin{align}
B_{1} &= \frac{2}{\pi} \, \int_{0}^{\pi} (ax \cos(x) + b \sin(x)) \, \sin(x) \, dx = \frac{2b-a}{2}
\end{align}
and calculating the general case for $n \geq 2$. Now choosing $a$ and $b$ as 
$a=2$ and $b=1$ then the reduction provides
\begin{align}
2 x \cos(x) + \sin(x) = 4 \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n} \, n}{n^{2}-1} \, \sin(n x).
\end{align}